# Making two compressed files form into one paragraph

Tags: python

I have this code that I am trying to decompress. First, I have compressed the code which is all working but then when I go onto decompressing it there is a ValueError.

```
    List.append(dic[int(bob)])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'
```

This is the code...

```
def menu():
    print("..........................................................")
    para = input("Please enter a paragraph.")
    print()
    s = para.split()  # splits sentence
    another = [0]  # will gradually hold all of the numbers repeated or not
    index = []  # empty index
    word_dictionary = []  # names word_dictionary variable

    for count, i in enumerate(s):  # has a count and an index for enumerating the split sentence
        if s.count(i) < 2:  # if it is repeated
            another.append(max(another) + 1)  # adds the other count to another
        else:  # if is has not been repeated
            another.append(s.index(i) +1)  # adds the index (i) to another 
    new = " "  # this has been added because other wise the numbers would be 01234567891011121341513161718192320214
    another.remove(0)  # takes away the 0 so that it doesn't have a 0 at the start

    for word in s:  # for every word in the list
        if word not in word_dictionary:  # If it's not in word_dictionary
            word_dictionary.append(word)  # adds it to the dicitonary
        else:  # otherwise
            s.remove(word)  # it will remove the word

    fo = open("indx.txt","w+")  # opens file
    for index in another:  # for each i in another
        index= str(index)  # it will turn it into a string
        fo.write(index)  # adds the index to the file
        fo.write(new)  # adds a space
    fo.close()  # closes file

    fo=open("words.txt", "w+")  # names a file sentence
    for word in word_dictionary:
        fo.write(str(word ))  # adds sentence to the file
        fo.write(new)
    fo.close()  # closes file

menu()

index=open("indx.txt","r+").read()
dic=open("words.txt","r+").read()

index= index.split()
dic = dic.split()

Num=0
List=[]

while Num != len(index):
    bob=index[Num]
    List.append(dic[int(bob)])
    Num+=1

print (List)
```

The problem is down on line 50. with ' List.append(dic[int(bob)])'.
Is there a way to get the Error message to stop popping up and for the code to output the sentence as inputted above?

Latest error message has occurred:
 List.append(dic[int(bob)])
IndexError: list index out of range

When I run the code, I input "This is a sentence. This is another sentence, with commas."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `index= index.split()` is by default splitting on spaces, and, as the exception shows, your numbers are separated by `,`s.

Without seeing `index.txt` I can't be certain if it will fix all of your indexes, but for the issue in OP, you can fix it by specifying what to split on, namely a comma:

```
index= index.split(',')
```

---

To your second issue, `List.append(dic[int(bob)]) IndexError: list index out of range` has two issues:

1. Your indexes start at 1, not 0, so you are off by one when reconstituting your array

This can be fixed with:

```
List.append(dic[int(bob) - 1])
```

---

Additionally you're doing a lot more work than you need to. This:

```
fo = open("indx.txt","w+")  # opens file
    for index in another:  # for each i in another
        index= str(index)  # it will turn it into a string
        fo.write(index)  # adds the index to the file
        fo.write(new)  # adds a space
    fo.close()  # closes file
```

is equivalent to:

```
with open("indx.txt","w") as fo:
    for index in another:
        fo.write(str(index) + new)
```

and this:

```
Num=0
List=[]

while Num != len(index):
    bob=index[Num]
    List.append(dic[int(bob)])
    Num+=1
```

is equivalent to

```
List = []
for item in index:
    List.append(dic[int(item)])
```

Also, take a moment to review [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and try to follow those standards. Your code is very difficult to read because it doesn't follow them. I fixed the formatting on your comments so StackOverflow's parser could parse your code, but most of them only add clutter.

Comment: In indx.txt , there is '1 2 3 4 1 2 5 6 7 8 '

Comment: @luna.ravenclaw Not according to your comments `fo.write(new)#adds a comma` and the exception you've gotten.

Comment: I hadn't changed that from earlier, sorry, it now says it adds a space.

Comment: @luna.ravenclaw You need to actually check your indx.txt file, as the exception shows what format the numbers are in `'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'`

Comment: I have just ran the code again and looked in my index file. 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 7 5 6 8 9 10 11

Comment: @luna.ravenclaw Your array indexes are off. I've added an explanation.